# FB.ui share dialog post and cancel have the same response

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this code below:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        title: 'test',
        href: 'http://google.com',
        picture: 'http://google.com/blah.jpg',
        caption: 'test caption',
        description: 'test description'

}, function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
        window.location="{{ config('app.url') }}/user/share/" + announcementId;
    } else {
        window.location=redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

the response for cancel and post to facebook in share dialog have a response of empty array. How will I track user when user clicks cancel button?

Comment: It is by design. Why do you need to know if they cancel?

Comment: because i want to track the user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do it is to implement the login and get "publish_actions" approved from the user. Doing this you will get a "post_id" back in the response if published.

**Note**: Rewarding users for sharing is violating FB terms